# confusing about the height of cell, UITableViewCell,iOS

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I am loading a custom cell from xib in which the height of cell is 64 and then using `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to change the height of cell like following :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect frame    =   CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    UINib *cellNIB                      =   [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([TableCell class]) bundle:nil];

    [tableView registerNib:cellNIB forCellReuseIdentifier:NSLocalizedString(@"TableCell", nil)];

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}

(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    return 400 ; 
}
```

At `cellForRowAtIndex`, I am printing out the height of cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TableCell *cell     =   [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSLocalizedString(@"TableCell", nil)];
    NSLog(@"height at:%ld is %@",(long)indexPath.item,NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
    [cell setGradient];

    return cell;
}
```

It is interesting that the console gives me the height of cell of 64 ( which comes from the xib )

Is it supposed to be 400 ?

Any ideas why I am getting 64 instead of 400. Any comments are welcomed here.
Thanks

PS :

```
@implementation TableCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Comment: Could you please show the code of your `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: my TableCell is subclass of UITableViewCell and I updated my post with its implement class ( actually, there is nothing new in the implement file )

Comment: Is there somehow you can set the `UITableViewCell` height programatically?

Comment: Yeah, the way cell height works is strange. I'm assuming the height is 400 on the screen, right?

Comment: @GabrielTomitsuka : yeah I can do it but I just wanna find down why I am getting 64 ( even though in the simulator, I can tell the size of cell is 400 )

Comment: 1) A cell's height is not set in the `cellForRowAtIndexHeight`. The cell isn't even in the table yet. So logging it there is meaningless. The height will be set by the time the cell is displayed. 2) Do not use the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method if all rows are the same height. Delete the method and add the following line in your `viewDidLoad` method: `tableView.rowHeight = 400;`. This is much more efficient when all rows have the same height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy actually.

In
 `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
 a cell gets reused (or created if the reuse queue is empty).
The cells initial height is either

- 44pt (for a cell loaded entirely from code)
- the height you specify in your nib (64pt, in your case)

However, the cell gets resized to the value you return from 
`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
AFTER you return it from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

So the behavior you're seeing to totally correct.

Tip: Implement
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
and log the height there, you'll see the cell has been resized to [400] in your case.